# extract part of a string before and after characters

Tags: php, string, variables, extract

I need to extract a variable based on a portion of a string. the string corresponds to a third level domain name, as in the example below.

```
$variable1 = "subdomain1.domain24.com"
$variable2 = "subdomain2.newdomain24.com"
```

I have to extract from the domain (therefore excluding the subdomain) the tld and the number 24. All domains ends with "24.com"

so result must be:

for variable1 : domain
for variable2 : newdomain

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions is one way for this kind of task

- the domain must follow a dot
- `24\.com$` is saying match 24.com at the end of the string

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

```
preg_match('/\.(?<domain>[^\.]+)24\.com$/', 'subdomain2.newdomain24.com', $matches );

var_dump($matches);

// array(3) {
//   [0]=> string(16) ".newdomain24.com"
//   ["domain"]=> string(9) "newdomain"
//   [1]=> string(9) "newdomain"
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

Explode your string on `.` and remove 2 last characters (as it always 24):

```php
$urls = [
    "subdomain1.domain24.com",
    "subdomain2.newdomain24.com",
];

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $parts = explode('.', $url);
    
    $domain = substr($parts[1], 0, -2);
    
    var_dump($domain);
}
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bf5e3baeca6abe470925c7bb949df9f7498945e0)